# Toggle doesn't work in OpenLayers 3 (using bind to)?

Tags: openlayers

My code says the error "undefined input"? I don't know what is wrong with my code:

`<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Map Examples</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/ol3/css/ol.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/samples.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="visible" checked> Toggle Layer Visibility
    <script src="../assets/ol3/js/ol.js"></script>
    <script>
      var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      });
      var london = ol.proj.transform([-0.12755, 51.507222], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
      var view = new ol.View({
        center: london,
        zoom: 6
      });
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [layer],
        view: view
      });
      // create a DOM Input helper for the checkbox
      var visible = new ol.dom.Input(document.getElementById('visible'));
      // and bind its 'checked' property to the layer's 'visible' property
      visible.bindTo('checked', layer, 'visible');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>`

Comment: Are you using a custom build?

Comment: Dear Jonatas, thank you for your answer, I am just new in developing a GIS web page, but as I understand the meaning of custom build, I downloaded the latest release of java script from openlayer site, and put it my folder. this code is one of the examples of "OpenLayers 3 Beginner's Guide" book. the link is : [link](https://openlayersbook.github.io/ch02-key-concepts-in-openlayers/example-03.html). the code works on the page but when I copy the exact code on my pc it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bindTo method was removed from ol.Object in version 3.6.x.  See https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3472 for further details.

You can use the [layer group](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/examples/layer-group.html) example to see how to bind inputs in a more generic way.  This example uses jQuery to help.